# How to create custom classes in orientdb using Gremlin

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I want the equivalant of this syntax in SQL:

```
create class Person extends V
```

in Gremlin

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to manipulate OrientDB schema through Gremlin. Gremlin is independent on OrientDB and is not adapted on schemas.

Comment: Yeah I suppose that would be the answer. don't you know any way to add a vertex in particular class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure it is possible to manipulate OrientDB schema through Gremlin. Gremlin is independent on OrientDB and is not adapted on schemas because not all of graph databases support schemas.

For adding vertex of particular class in OrientDB you can use Graph API (see [doc](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html)). If you prepend string `class:` before the name of the class, you will create a vertex of this class.

```
graph.addVertex("class:User");
```

This snippet will create vertex of class `User`. I hope it will help you.