# How to create sub class of superclass V in graph using gremlin console

Tags: gremlin

I tried stackoverflow, gremlin docs. But couldn't find the solution.
I tried:

```
g.v('class:Employee',[EmpId:'398']);
```

It created one vertex. But again I tried with different value. I couldn't insert new vertex.

```
gremlin> g.addVertex('Class:Employee',[EmpId:'589'])
groovysh_parse: 51: expecting '(', found 'g' @ line 51, column 1.
   g.addVertex('Class:Employee',[EmpId:'589'])
```

Answer (score 1):

That error usually means that the input buffer is messed up because you had a syntax error from the previous line.  In this case it looks like the buffer is expecting an open parenthesis, but you've instead started a new command.  These issue can be fixed with a call to `clear`:

```
gremlin> clear
```

Comment: Thank You...it worked. But concern remains still. I want to create subclass of V. I again tried query after clear. It replaced previous record with class employee. I again did query with different id. It gave me this.                                              gremlin> g.addVertex('Class:Employee',[EmpId:'986'])
Vertex with id already exists: Class:Employee

Comment: I assume that you are using OrientDB.  If so, I believe that this is the correct syntax: `g.addVertex("class:Employee")`.  I guess the problem is your use of an uppercase "C" in "class".  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29691471/1831717)

Comment: I tried with the lowercase also. I am not using orientDB. I didn't connect my graph to any database. It was just temporary(volatile) graph of kind TinkerGraph. I didn't use any orientDB query or syntax.....only gremlin syntax.

Comment: Well - "class:Employee" is not gremlin syntax.  Gremlin/TinkerGraph has no notion of "classes".  When you use TinkerGraph and do `g.addVertex("class:Employee")` you are telling TinkerGraph to create a vertex with a vertex identifier of "class:Employee", which is why when you tried to create it a second time you got: "Vertex with id already exists".